# how to count anohter model django?

Tags: django

Hope You Are Good

I Have These Models:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    priority = models.CharField(max_length=124, choices=priority_options, default="Low")
    status = models.CharField(max_length=124, choices=status_options, default="In Progress")
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    invite = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="invite", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Issue(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    issue = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task.name
```

Now i Have used this Command To Count Tasks:

```
Task.objects.filter(user=request.user,status="Completed").count()
```

now I want to find the task which created by this user and status is completed issues

how can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understood from your question you want all the Issues belonging to the Tasks you have filtered.

You can use

```py
tasks = Task.objects.filter(user=request.user, status="Completed")
count = tasks.count()
issues = Issue.objects.filter(task__in=tasks)
```

The `__in` addition to a field is documented here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#id4

Comment: but we can't use count!

Comment: sorry, I meant to remove the .count(). I will edit my response, and show you how to get the count.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this with the field lookup [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#in).

```
tasks = Task.objects.filter(user=request.user,status="Completed")
issues = Issue.objects.filter(task__in=tasks)
```